# triangle texture is rotating and flipping horizontally

Tags: c++, raytracing

writing a ray tracer for class, and I'm getting an odd issue I can't seem to nail down the source of. I've got my texture and for some reason its rotating 90 clockwise, then flipping horizontally. I'm using barycentric coordinates to navigate my uv space coordinates.

I've already attempted to play with how i'm generating u,v,w. but it seems to result in the same issue.

[In program issue visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dafpi.png)
[my actual test texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfm1D.png)

```
//how i'm generating my barycentric coordinates:
Ph = Pe + Npe*Th; //Ph is the point in space that is being tested, I'm generating u,v,w while testing inside/outside triangle (Pe = Point of eye, Npe = vector from eye to point on triangle, Th = time hit)

        A = glm::cross(P1 - P0, P2 - P0);
        //glm::vec3 A0 = glm::cross(Ph - P1, Ph - P2);
        //glm::vec3 A1 = glm::cross(Ph - P2, Ph - P0);
        //glm::vec3 A2 = glm::cross(Ph - P0, Ph - P1);
        glm::vec3 A0 = glm::cross(P1-Ph, P2-Ph);
        glm::vec3 A1 = glm::cross(P2-Ph, P0-Ph);
        glm::vec3 A2 = glm::cross(P0-Ph, P1-Ph);

        if (glm::dot(n0, glm::normalize(A0)) < 0 || glm::dot(n0, glm::normalize(A1)) < 0 || glm::dot(n0, glm::normalize(A2)) < 0)
        {
            //point is outside triangle
            return -1;
        }


        //normalize and chec k dot products to detrmine if they are facing the right way.

        u = glm::length(A0) / glm::length(A);
        v = glm::length(A1) / glm::length(A);
        w = 1 - u - v;
```

And then here is the portion that uses that to calculate the texture coordinates.

```
//portion of code calculating texture coordinates
//calculate new location of texture coordinate, assume z position is 0
        glm::vec3 textureCo = P0TexCo*this->u + P1TexCo*this->v + P2TexCo*this->w;
        u = textureCo[0];
        v = textureCo[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it had to do with how opengl interprets coordinates and what corner it starts in for displaying pixels from an array. the solution is to invert the image after you load it in.